# Get the intersection of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I'm a bit of a maths noob but I have the problem that I have two functions of the following form:

$$f(x) = 0.1 x + 3 \quad \text{ and } \quad  f(y) = 0.3 y + 400 $$

meaning that I have a graph where I have a "normal" line in my plot and a vertical line which is dependent on $y$ and not $x$.

I am now trying to get the intersection of these two functions but I do not really know how to do this. I am helpful for any answers! Thank you.
[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4YCC.png). How can I get the intersection of the blue line with the orange or the green one?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I think the notation is a bit unlucky: Are you asking for the intersection of the lines $$\{(x,\frac x{10}+3)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$$ and $$\{(\frac{3y}{10}+400,y)\mid y\in\mathbb R\}$$ or of the first line and $$\{(y, \frac{3y}{10}+400)\mid y\in\mathbb R\}$$ ?

Comment: Sorry for the bad notation: I meant the first two ones. 
{(x,x10+3)∣x∈R} and
{(3y10+400,y)∣y∈R}

Comment: I still don't quite understand what you mean. When you say "I have a graph where I have a normal line" - What kind of graph do you mean? What's the relationship between $f$ and the graph? Normally, one would set $y=f(x)$ and then draw the set of points $(x,y)$ in a Cartesian plane. But in this case these variables seem to be mixed up. Also, do you mean to say that $f(y)=0.3y+400$ is a vertical line? In what way can it be a vertical line?

Comment: It's also confusing to use the same letter $f$ for two different functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the intersection of the lines

$y=0.1x+3$

and

$x=0.3y+400$

then you can just substitute $0.1x+3$ for $y$ in the second equation to get

$x=0.3(0.1x+3) +400 = 0.03x + 400.9$

and then solve this equation to find the value of $x$.

Comment: I think you got the gist of what he means!

Answer (score 0):

If we have a line written as a function of $x$, such as $y=ax+b$, then we can rewrite it as a function of $y$ by "solving for x", that is $x=\frac{1}{a}(y-b)$, and similarly we can go the other way
$$x = ay+b \Rightarrow y = \frac{1}{a}(x-b) \quad \quad (\text{provided that }a\neq0)$$
So in order to solve your problem, we can convert $g(y)=0.3y+400$ into a function of $x$ using the method above
$$x = \frac{3}{10}y+400 \Rightarrow y = \frac{10}{3}(x-400)=\frac{10}3 x - \frac{4000}{3}$$
Now we can find the $x$-coordinate by solving
$$\frac{x}{10} + 3 = \frac{10}3 x - \frac{4000}{3}$$